# Where does stomp_interface come from?

Tags: datastax-enterprise

In order to enable https communications between OpsCenter and DSE nodes, I have to set stomp_interface to opscenter.mydomain.com in /var/lib/datastax-agent/conf/address.yaml on each node.  (After the fix, I no longer have to do this.)

Whenever I do a configure job from OpsCenter, it changes this stomp_interface value back to nn.nn.nn.nn.  (After the fix, it still does this, but it doesn't break the agent HTTP communications anymore.)

Where does this parameter come from?  Can I set it on the OpsCenter node in the /etc/opscenter/clusters/cluster_name.conf file?

Is it part of the [agents] section?

What is the parameter name and value that I should be adding?

opscenterd is now (the fix was to add the incoming_interface line):

```
# opscenterd.conf
[webserver]
port = 8888
interface = 0.0.0.0

ssl_keyfile = /var/lib/opscenter/ssl/opscenter.key
ssl_certfile = /var/lib/opscenter/ssl/opscenter.pem
ssl_port = 8443

[authentication]
enabled = True

[stat_reporter]

[agents]
use_ssl = true
incoming_interface = opscenter.mydomain.com
```

address.yaml before fix:

```
use_ssl: 1
stomp_interface: 1.2.3.4 (the opscenter external IP.
                          opscenter.mydomain.com also works)
stomp_port: 61620
local_interface: 2.3.4.5 (the external IP for this cluster node)
agent_rpc_interface: 0.0.0.0
agent_rpc_broadcast_address: 2.3.4.5
poll_period: 60
disk_usage_update_period: 60
rollup_rate: 200
rollup_rate_unit: second
jmx_host: 127.0.0.1
jmx_port: 7199
jmx_user: someuser
jmx_pass: somepassword
status_reporting_interval: 20
ec2_metadata_api_host: 169.254.169.254
metrics_enabled: true
jmx_metrics_threadpool_size: 5
hosts: ["2.3.4.5", "3.4.5.6", "4.5.6.7", "5.6.7.8"]
cassandra_port: 9042
thrift_port: 9160
cassandra_user: someuser
cassandra_pass: somepassword
runs_sudo: true
cassandra_install_location: /usr/share/dse
cassandra-conf: /etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
cassandra_binary_location: /usr/bin
cassandra_conf_location: /etc/dse/cassandra
dse_env_location: /etc/dse
dse_binary_location: /usr/bin
dse_conf_location: /etc/dse
spark_conf_location: /etc/dse/spark
monitored_cassandra_user: someuser
monitored_cassandra_pass: somepassword
tcp_response_timeout: 120000
pong_timeout_ms: 120000
```

cluster_name.conf (I updated the seed_hosts to match those in the address.yaml hosts config in order to satisfy a Best Practices alert
that they should all be the same):

```
[destinations]
active =

[kerberos]
default_service =
opscenterd_client_principal =
opscenterd_keytab_location =
agent_keytab_location =
agent_client_principal =

[agents]
ssl_keystore_password =
ssl_keystore =

[jmx]
password = somepassword
port = 7199
username = someuser

[cassandra]
ssl_truststore_password =
cql_port = 9042
seed_hosts = 2.3.4.5, 3.4.5.6, 4.5.6.7, 5.6.7.8
username = someuser
password = somepassword
ssl_keystore_password =
ssl_keystore =
ssl_truststore =
```

Comment: This value is normally sent down from the `opscenterd` process to the agents. I was under the impression that if you set the value in the `address.yaml` it should not overwrite it unless you're selecting to install the agents manually. Can you post your `opscenterd.conf`, `cluster_name.conf` and `address.yaml` please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment for further information, I figured it out.

I added the incoming_interface = opscenter.mydomain.com to the [agents] section of the opscenterd.conf.  (That wasn't present before markc's comment.)

I restarted service opscenterd.

Next, I was able to go back to OpsCenter LifeCycle Manager and do a fresh Install and Configure on the cluster, and all of the job steps completed successfully.

(Note:  Don't change the rack names on nodes from what they were before, and select autoBootStrap = true on the Configure / Install requests.)

The datastax-agents are fully Up and Active.  After the Configure and Install, the address.yaml files contained the public IP address of the OpsCenter node as the stomp_interface.  (I changed one stomp_interface manually to be opscenter.mydomain.com, and that also works.)

I will also edit the question and post the requested information.

Thanks markc!

Comment: glad to have helped. I must say your `address.yaml` is quite full though, in my ~2 years of working with OpsCenter on and off I've not seen such a long list of options used in this file. Are you sure you need all of them?